# Como descargar fichero en php y javaScript

Tags: php, html, css

Necesito descargar un fichero de en php, si tienen el codigo que me lo puedan facilitar se los agradeceria....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCION**

Solo tienes que usar esta funcion

```
function descargar($fichero){

    $basefichero = basename($fichero);
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fichero));
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=" .$basefichero."");
    readfile($fichero);
      }
```

tienes que cambiar el $fichero por el nombre del documento ya descargado en tu proyecto y el basefichero es donde esta alojado el archivo espero te ayude!

Comment: Gracias bro !! me sirvió tu codigo, muchas gracias !!